# What is meant precisely, when a term in the Lagrangian is "chirally invariant"?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, spinors, chirality, invariants

I am reading [this](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevC.84.045208) paper, where eq. (2):
$$ m_0(\bar{\phi}_{-L}\phi_{+R}-\bar{\phi}_{-R}\phi_{+L}-\bar{\phi}_{+L}\phi_{-R}+\bar{\phi}_{+R}\phi_{-L}) \tag{2} $$
is said to be **chirally invariant**. Here, the $\phi$'s represent Weyl left- and right-handed spinors (I believe) with the indexed parity.

At first I thought chirally invariant would mean performing the tranformation $L\leftrightarrow R$ would leave the term invariant, but this is not the case (you pick up an extra minus sign). Does it have something to do with parity? If so, why exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a link to a free version on arxiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.2596

Eq (1) defines what the authors mean by a chiral transformation
\begin{eqnarray}
\varphi_{+R}' &=& R\varphi_{+R} \\
\varphi_{+L}' &=& L\varphi_{+L} \\
\varphi_{-R}' &=& L\varphi_{-R} \\
\varphi_{-L}' &=& R\varphi_{-L}
\end{eqnarray}
where $R$ and $L$ are rotations in the right- and left- handed subspaces.

Using these transformations in the first mass term, we see
\begin{equation}
\bar\varphi'_{-L} \varphi'_{+R} = \bar\varphi_{-L} R^\dagger R \varphi_{+R} = \bar\varphi_{-L} \varphi_{+R}
\end{equation}
since for rotations, $R^\dagger R = 1$.

The other terms in Eq (2) are similarly invariant under the transformation in Eq (1).